# send_message - Building Chatbots in Python - Datacamp

Tags: python

How to modify the function <send_message> to recreate the datacamp exercise:

```
# Define a respond function
state = INIT
def respond(state, message):
    (new_state, response) = policy_rules[(state, interpret(message))]
    return new_state, response


# Create templates
bot_template = "BOT : {0}"
user_template = "USER : {0}"

def send_message(state, message):
    new_state, response = respond(state, message)
    return new_state


# Define the INIT state
INIT = 0

# Define the CHOOSE_COFFEE state
CHOOSE_COFFEE = 1

# Define the ORDERED state
ORDERED = 2

# Define the policy rules
policy = {
    (INIT, "order"): (CHOOSE_COFFEE, "ok, Colombian or Kenyan?"),
    (INIT, "none"): (INIT, "I'm sorry - I'm not sure how to help you"),
    (CHOOSE_COFFEE, "specify_coffee"): (ORDERED, "perfect, the beans are on their way!"),
    (CHOOSE_COFFEE, "none"): (CHOOSE_COFFEE, "I'm sorry - would you like Colombian or Kenyan?"),
}

# Create the list of messages
messages = [
    "I'd like to become a professional dancer",
    "well then I'd like to order some coffee",
    "my favourite animal is a zebra",
    "kenyan"
]

# Call send_message() for each message
state = INIT
for message in messages:    
    state = send_message(policy, state, message)
```

The output of the function is:

USER : I'd like to become a professional dancer
BOT : I'm sorry - I'm not sure how to help you
USER : well then I'd like to order some coffee
BOT : ok, Colombian or Kenyan?
USER : my favourite animal is a zebra
BOT : I'm sorry - would you like Colombian or Kenyan?
USER : kenyan
BOT : perfect, the beans are on their way!

Thanks a lot.